# GPS and direction in Google Maps not working correct with S5

Tags: google-maps-navigation, gps-tracking

I have a Galaxy S5 and I am using Google Maps or Komoot to navigate with my bycicle. I am in the mode, so the map directs to where I am facing to. Walking works fine and cycling very slow too. But cycling above 15 km/h the map shakes around and its not working correct anymore.

Does anyone knows howto fix this or what is the problem ?

Comment: A good mobile signal is needed for proper navigation support.

Comment: I dont think thats the problem. Locically  Otherwise it would also be a problem with low velocity.

Comment: Velocity would never be a problem. I've used Google maps at 80kmph. It's accurate. Is it the problem with Komoot?